# vs2015 C++ include directory gstreamer

Tags: c++, visual-c++, path, include

i'm trying to compile `gstreamer sdk` tutorials on `vs2015` in C++.

Problem: I always get a fatal error,

```
fatal error C1083: unable to open include file 'gst/gst.h': no such file or directory.
```

from the basic-tutorial1.c the include is

```
#include <gst/gst.h>
```

the file needed,  gst.h is in the directory

```
C:\gstreamer-sdk\0.10\x86_64\include\gstreamer-0.10\gst
```

in vs2015,on basic-tutorial1,in property `->config property->VC++ paths->include paths`,

I have

```
C:\gstreamer-sdk\0.10\x86_64\include\gstreamer-0.10;
$(GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT_X86_64);
$(IncludePath)
```

GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT_X86_64  is defined as C:\gstreamer-sdk\0.10\x86_64\

it seems a basic problem,but I have tried some path and combinations, but can't include the file.

The only solution working  is to set the full path to `gst.h` in the include directive. It's crazy.

This include is the start file for multiples include, and there is the same problem for each one..

How can I set the include directive or path correctly? It's incredible that's this product is unable to do this simply.

Answer (score 0):

Either the Path in the Include directives is wrong,
Or there can be a permission issue.

Check that u have permissions for include file folder and the solution folder.
One simple option is move everything, include files and solution in documents folder, reset include directives and try to rebuild it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et4zwx34.aspx

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts, may be worth using GStreamer 1.0 rather than 0.1. Also, you need to install the devel and normal versions. You seem to be using the defunct SDK.

Downloads from: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/windows/1.8.0/

If you are building for 64 bit, and consuming HLS content, watch out for this problem: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=758738. Its easy to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem today.
I am using VS 2017 & wanted to work gstreamer and landed in to the same problem.

After a lot of struggle, I realized the the mistake committed was : ***I downloaded the wrong package for installing***

The package which I downloaded was : `gstreamer-1.0-x86_64-1.14.3.msi` which game a folder structure without containing the development files.

Hence, I went back to [the download link](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/windows/1.14.3/) and downloaded `gstreamer-1.0-devel-x86_64-1.14.3.msi`

This has all the dev files.

Now all you need to do after this is set the VS project directories to this and you are good to go.

Hope this helps!!!